# What does this word represent?

Tags: puzzle

What five digit number does serve represent if VCR+VCCT=SERVE? I have tried using 4,5,and 6 for C but that doesn't seem to work. Please help I do not understand.

Answer (score 2):

943+9447=10390. So C=4 does work.

Below is how I got this:

3 digit number + 4 digit number = 5 digit number, so it is easy to see that the sum < 1000+10000=11000, so the result is 10RVE, i.e., S=1, E=0. Also, V=9, otherwise sum < 1000+9000 =10000 (cannot be 5 digit number). With V = 9, look at the second last digits in the summation, which is C+C+(possible carried 1 from the summation of last digits) = V = 9, so C=4, and R+T=1E=10. From summation of third digit you have V+C=1R, where you already have V=9 and C=4, so R=3. At last from R+T=10 you get T=7. All set.